# Cakephp PCRE message?

Tags: cakephp, message

After installing my cakephp site. i got this message in yellow background.

```
PCRE has not been compiled with Unicode support.
Recompile PCRE with Unicode support by adding --enable-unicode-properties when configuring
```

I dont know what this means. Plz anybody explain, what this means?

i am using cakephp version 1.3.7

Answer (score 2):

It means what it says, the [PCRE extension](http://php.net/PCRE) was built without Unicode support, which may lead to a [number of bugs](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/tickets?q=pcre). You should recompile the extension, or use a different server/package/installation that includes a properly compiled PCRE library. This may be a question appropriate for http://serverfault.com.

Comment: This happens a lot on Red Hat and CentOS since the version that comes from their respective package managers were compiled with this misconfiguration.